# Express JavaScript Supertest Expect specific json fields

Tags: javascript, express, supertest

I'm attempting to write some unit tests for API endpoints, and decided on JavaScript Express w/ Supertest. I've got the basic downs, but running into issues checking the response for a specific field. I want to parse the body and check if an expected field returns and has the correct value. Most everything I've seen online uses this method, but when I try it always passes, even when I enter values I know don't exist in the JSON. Any advice? Here is my code snippet:

```
describe('GET category', function () {
    it('response w/ only injury returned', function () {
        request('endpoint')
            .get('path')
            .set('header', 'token')
            .expect(200)
            .then(response => {
                console.assert(response.body, "Baseball")
            })
    })
});
```

I have also tried changing the .then to .expect, with same results. If I do response.body.specificFieldinBody I get similar results. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do with your way - use `.then` syntax, but I think use `Supertest` assertion syntax will be good.

This mean, use `response.body.should.have.property("Baseball");` instead of `console.assert(response.body, "Baseball")` (`Baseball` is your special field).

Or, My suggestion is creating a re-use code: Put a assertion callback function to a next `expects` section.

```
const isIncludeField = function (fieldName) {
  return function (res) {
    res.body.should.have.property(fieldName);
  };
}

describe('GET category', function () {
  it('response w/ only injury returned', function () {
    request('endpoint')
      .get('path')
      .set('header', 'token')
      .expect(200)
      .expect(isIncludeField('Baseball')) // 
      .end(done); // call done callback
  })
});
```

Comment: This is similar to what I've been trying, but the should.* asserts give me a "Cannot read property 'have' of undefined. Is there something in my package.json or some dependency I'm missing?

`
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "supertest": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha 'test/apiTest.js'"
  }
}
`

Comment: `done` was never defined. Better to return the promise chain in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues:

1. `console.assert(response.body, "Baseball")` only checks whether `response.body` is truthy. `"Baseball"` is just the message that prints if it isn't (i.e. `Assertion failed: Baseball`). You may be looking for

   ```js
   console.assert(response.body.Baseball, "body.Baseball should be defined")
   ```

   or you may want to assert that the value for a particular key equals `"Baseball"`; something like

   ```js
   console.assert(response.body.injury === "Baseball", "body.injury === 'Baseball'")
   ```
2. `console.assert` just logs the failure to the console, which likely [won't be picked up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833456/why-is-my-test-case-passes-but-the-assertion-actually-failed-in-mocha) by whatever testing library you're using (Mocha, Jest). I suggest using an assertion library like Chai, Jest's built-in assertions, or at least Node's native `assert` so the test will show as a failure.
3. `request('endpoint')` returns a promise. If the test suite isn't appraised of the asynchronous nature of the test, it'll happily give you an instant pass without actually running any assertions. Use `return request('endpoint')` to ensure that the test suite awaits for the promise chain to resolve and detects any assertions.

Marking your test `async` helps reduce the footgun factor and is generally cleaner than `.then()` or callbacks (less nesting). Here's a complete example you can run with `npx mocha server.test.js`.

`server.test.js`:

```js
const assert = require("assert");
const request = require("supertest");
const app = require("./server");

describe("GET category", () => {
  it("response with only injury returned", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).get("/path");
    assert(response.status === 200);
    assert(response.body.injury === "Baseball");
  });

  // ... or use supertest's assertions:
  it("response with only injury returned (alternate approach)", () => {
    return request(app)
      .get("/path")
      .expect(200, {injury: "Baseball"});
  });
});
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/path", (req, res) => res.json({injury: "Baseball"}));

module.exports = app;
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^10.3.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4"
  }
}
```