# Why is my test case passes but the assertion actually failed in mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

My test case below passes but my Assertion failed. Why is it passing? I already have async in place and the updateSpy is not even called which is confirmed by my Assertion failed message. I also tried Done with promises.

```
it('should call the update  method once', async () => {
        const updateSpy = sinon.spy(() => 'Spy!');
    
        sinon.stub(service, 'db').resolves({
          collection(collectionName) {
            return {
              update: updateSpy,

                  };
          },
        });

       console.assert(updateSpy.called); // assertion failed but the test case was passed
  });
```

Comment: Because you are `console.assert`. This just logs the result of the assertion to the console. You need to use an assertion library which will throw an Error so that Mocha knows the assertion failed.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ASSERTIONS](https://mochajs.org/#assertions) doc:

> Mocha allows you to use any assertion library you wish. In the above example, we’re using Node.js’ built-in `assert` module — but generally, if it throws an `Error`, it will work!

But [console.assert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/assert) method writes an error message to the console if the assertion is false. If the assertion is true, nothing happens. It will **NOT** throw an `Error` if the assertion is false.